# Angular: possible to queries elements of all DOM from a specific component?

Tags: angular, viewchildren

With the DOM snippets below:

```
<ng-app>
  <ng-comp1></ng-comp1>
  <ng-comp2>
     <ng-comp3></ng-comp3>
  </ng-comp2>
  <ng-comp1></ng-comp1>
</ng-app>
```

I would like from `ng-comp3` to list all components `ng-comp1` in DOM document. There is a way for that ?

`ViewChildren` list only components inside `ng-comp3`.

`document.querySelector` list DOM element, not the component.

Comment: I'm curious to why you want this. My feeling is that you possibly should reconsider your design. I'm guessing the problem can be solved in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No, you cannot directly list them".

What you can do, on the other hand, is to have the `ng-app` injected in your `ng-comp3` component and interact with the `ng-comp1` via the `ng-app`.

[I have put an example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhz8zm?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class InnerHelloComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) private app: AppComponent) {
    console.log(app.name);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Here you will be able to access your ViewChild
  }
}
```

Don't forget that the `ViewChild` and `ViewChildren` do not get populated until `ngAfterViewInit` gets fired

The idea, as may have noticed, is to query for `ng-comp1` in the `ng-app` component, store that in a public variable and access it from the `ng-comp3`. The same way I am accessing the property `name` in my example

Comment: So I have tried to implement `@ViewChildren(ng-comp1)`  in NgApp and access it from ng-comp3 but tViewChildren not list component in `ng-comp2` for instance :/

Comment: I have done the whole example on Stackblitz (check the link).
You can see there that all components are visible via the `ngApp`.

Comment: In fact, I think that my `ng-comp3` is not initialized during initialization do I can't see it with @ViewChildren. But your example work fine. However, I can't solve my issue with this way. My initial issue is https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17421 and I think that I can solve it by list all `ion-router-outlet` and interact  with the child directly, but I not found the way to access it.